# Add multiple records to model's collection Sailsjs

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I have the following models in my Sailsjs application with a many-to-many relationship:

event.js:

```
attributes: {
 title : { type: 'string', required: true },
 description : { type: 'string', required: true },
 location : { type: 'string', required: true },
 maxMembers : { type: 'integer', required: true },
 currentMembers : { collection: 'user', via: 'eventsAttending', dominant: true },
 creator : { model: 'user', required: true },
 invitations : { collection: 'invitation', via: 'eventID' },
 tags : { collection: 'tag', via: 'taggedEvents', dominant: true },
 lat : { type: 'float' },
 lon : { type: 'float' },
},
```

tags.js:

```
attributes: {
 tagName : { type: 'string', unique: true, required: true },
 taggedEvents : { collection: 'event', via: 'tags' },
},
```

Based on the documentation, this relationship looks correct. I have the following method in tag.js that accepts an array of tag strings, and an event id, and is supposed to add or remove the tags that were passed in:

```
modifyTags: function (tags, eventId) {
var tagRecords = [];

_.forEach(tags, function(tag) {
    Tag.findOrCreate({tagName: tag}, {tagName: tag}, function (error, result) {
        tagRecords.push({id: result.id})
    })
})

Event.findOneById(eventId).populate('tags').exec(function(error, event){
    console.log(event)
    var currentTags = event.tags;
    console.log(currentTags)
    delete currentTags.add;
    delete currentTags.remove;

    if (currentTags.length > 0) {
      currentTags = _.pluck(currentTags, 'id');
    }

    var modifiedTags = _.pluck(tagRecords, 'id');
    var tagsToAdd = _.difference(modifiedTags, currentTags);
    var tagsToRemove = _.difference(currentTags, modifiedTags);
    console.log('current', currentTags)
    console.log('remove', tagsToRemove)
    console.log('add', tagsToAdd)

    if (tagsToAdd.length > 0) {
      _.forEach(tagsToAdd, function (tag) {
        event.tags.add(tag);
      })
        event.save(console.log)
    }

    if (tagsToRemove.length > 0) { 
      _.forEach(tagsToRemove, function (tagId) {
         event.tags.remove(tagId)
      })
       event.save()
    }      
})
}
```

This is how the method is called from the event model:

```
afterCreate: function(record, next) {
  Tag.modifyTags(tags, record.id)
  next();
}
```

When I post to event/create, I get this result: http://pastebin.com/PMiqBbfR.

It looks as if the method call itself is looped over, rather than just the tagsToAdd or tagsToRemove array. Whats more confusing is that at the end, in the last log of the event, it looks like the event has the correct tags. When I then post to event/1, however, the tags array is empty. I've also tried saving immediately after each `.add()`, but still get similar results.

Ideally, I'd like to loop over both the tagsToAdd and tagsToRemove arrays, modify their ids in the model's collection, and then call `.save()` once on the model.

I have spent a ton of time trying to debug this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your implementation, but the main issue is that you're treating certain methods--namely [`.save()`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/records/save.html) and [`.findOrCreate`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/findOrCreate.html) as *synchronous methods*, when they are (like all Waterline methods) *asynchronous*, requiring a callback.  So you're effectively running a bunch of code in parallel and not waiting for it to finish before returning.

Also, since it seems like what you're trying to do is *replace* the current event tags with this new list, the method you came up with is a bit over-engineered--you don't need to use `event.tags.add` and `event.tags.remove`.  You can just use plain old `update`.

So you could probably rewrite the `modifyTags` method as:

```
modifyTags: function (tags, eventId, mainCb) {

  // Asynchronously transform the `tags` array into an array of Tag records
  async.map(tags, function(tag, cb) {
    // For each tag, find or create a new record.
    // Since the async.map `cb` argument expects a function with 
    // the standard (error, result) node signature, this will add
    // the new (or existing) Tag instance to the resulting array.
    // If an error occurs, async.map will exit early and call the
    // "done()" function below
    Tag.findOrCreate({tagName: tag}, {tagName: tag}, cb);
  }, function done (err, tagRecords) {
    if (err) {return mainCb(err);}
    // Update the event with the new tags
    Event.update({id: eventId}, {tags: tagRecords}).exec(mainCb);
  });

}
```

See the full docs for `async.map` [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#map).

If you wanted to stick with your implementation using `.add` and `.remove`, you would still want to use `async.map`, and do the rest of your logic in the `done` method.  You don't need two `.save` calls; just do run all the `.add` and `.remove` code first, then do a single `.save(mainCb)` to finish it off.

And I don't know what you're trying to accomplish by deleting the `.add` and `.remove` methods from `currentTags` (which is a direct reference to `event.tags`), but it won't work and will just cause confusion later!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had a feeling it was due to asynchronous methods based on what I was finding online. I'm still very new to asynchronous/synchronous methods and callbacks, and after taking your suggestion, I'm still getting errors and am a bit confused. I've asked a followup question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800157/add-multiple-records-to-models-collection-sailsjs-followup